# Laravel code to clean unwanted Object properties and extract only needed attributes in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

In Laravel 5.4 I have sqlite database and with the code below. What I am trying to return from below code is only Article table columns (id,title,description) values and nothing more. When I use Var_dump() it returns unnecessary objects properties.

```
public function home()
    {
        $articles=Article::get();
        return view('home',['items'=>$articles]); // any name can be given 
    }
{{var_dump($items)}}
```

as listed below.

```
`object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#189 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    object(App\Article)#190 (25) {
      ["connection":protected]=>
      string(6) "sqlite"
      ["table":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["primaryKey":protected]=>
      string(2) "id"
      ["keyType":protected]=>
      string(3) "int"
      ["incrementing"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["with":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["withCount":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["perPage":protected]=>
      int(15)
      ["exists"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["attributes":protected]=>
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["title"]=>
        string(7) "Laravel"
        ["description"]=>
        string(34) "Laravel is Powerful Php Framework."
        ["created_at"]=>
        string(19) "2018-09-10 17:04:38"
        ["updated_at"]=>
        string(19) "2018-09-10 17:04:38"
      }
      ["original":protected]=>
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["title"]=>
        string(7) "Laravel"
        ["description"]=>
        string(34) "Laravel is Powerful Php Framework."
        ["created_at"]=>
        string(19) "2018-09-10 17:04:38"
        ["updated_at"]=>
        string(19) "2018-09-10 17:04:38"
      }

}`
```

What I want is a code that returns an object properties with the exact attributes like below.

```
["attributes":protected]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "Laravel"
    ["description"]=>
    string(34) "Laravel is Powerful Php Framework."
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2018-09-10 17:04:38"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2018-09-10 17:04:38"
  }
```

Any good solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is right

```
public function home()
{
    $articles=Article::get();
    return view('home',['items'=>$articles]); // any name can be given 
}
```

and in your view to see the output

```
{{ dd($items) }}
```

also dont worry about extra params with var_dump, access only the needful now

Answer (score 0):

In the top of the `Article` model add the certain table columns that you want to filter out, to this `$hidden`  array

```
protected $hidden = [
    'user_password', 'remember_token',
];
```